# Formula with conditions

Tags: community, formula

I want to develop a functional formula that will count 3 fields and gives me 3 different values depends of the final result.

```
Twitter_Fans__c + Facebook_Fans__c + Linkedin_Followers__c =< 5000 , should give 0
Twitter_Fans__c + Facebook_Fans__c + Linkedin_Followers__c >= 5000 , should give 5
Twitter_Fans__c + Facebook_Fans__c + Linkedin_Followers__c >= 10000 , should give 10
```

This is where i am now:

```
IF( Formula_SUM_Social__c  < 5000, 0,  IF(Formula_SUM_Social__c   >=  5000, 5,  IF(Formula_SUM_Social__c   >=  10000, 10, null) ) )
```

With the formula above the last IF doesn't give a value of 10.

Please advise.

Comment: The formatting change I had made was to put your formulas into code blocks which makes them easier for others to read.

Comment: Thank you @BarCotter but the formula that was changed was not functional properly for values above 10k. It was giving value of 0 because both >=5k and >=10k had miscalculated values.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice that the formula in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Working solution:

```
IF( Formula_SUM_Social__c > 0 && Formula_SUM_Social__c < 5000, 0, 
IF( Formula_SUM_Social__c >= 5000 && Formula_SUM_Social__c < 10000 , 5, 
IF( Formula_SUM_Social__c >= 10000, 10, null) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

In your formula `Formula_SUM_Social__c   >=  5000` will always be true once `Formula_SUM_Social__c`  is greater than 5,000 and 10,000

There are a different ways you could do this, such as the one below.

```
IF( Formula_SUM_Social__c  < 5000, 0,  
IF(Formula_SUM_Social__c   <  10000, 5, 
IF(Formula_SUM_Social__c   >=  10000, 10, 
null) ) )
```

Or if you wanted to keep your original IF statements you could reverse the order of them so that it will give the correct results

```
IF(Formula_SUM_Social__c   >=  10000, 10, 
IF(Formula_SUM_Social__c   >=  5000, 5, 
IF( Formula_SUM_Social__c  < 5000, 0,  
null) ) )
```

Comment: this is another way of my answer thanks for making my code smaller :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this to:

```
CASE( 
  FLOOR( Formula_SUM_Social__c / 5000 ), /* Round Formula_SUM_Social__c / 5000 down to nearest integer */
  0, 0, /* If integer result is 0 (0 <= Formula_SUM_Social__c < 5000), returns 0 */
  1, 5, /* If integer result is 1 (5000 <= Formula_SUM_Social__c < 10000), returns 5 */
  10 /* Any other result (Formula_SUM_Social__c >= 10000) returns 10 */
)
```

The value of this method is that if Formula_SUM_Social__c ever ends up becoming a more complex formula (say you add additional social media fields to your sum), you only reference its compile size once, rather than 5 times. And it also makes it easy to add additional levels, or change your variance (say you change it to 2500 instead of 5000).